# Can VBA take a multiline string like Python can?

Tags: python, vba

In Python, I can create a multi-line string by using """.

For instance:

```
x = """

Hello
World """"
```

Is there a way to do this with VBA?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, VBA does not have multi-line strings.

Comment: Well that sucks! :( Thanks for the quick answer though! :)

Comment: You can use string concatenation with `&`, line continuation with `_` if your strings are too long but you must use `vbNewLine` to have a string containing a new line character.

Comment: Yeah, but there is a limit to line continuation in VBA, right?

Answer (score 1):

This drives me insane every single time I want to work with a multi-line string in VBA, so I wrote a little Python script that reads from stdin and spits out VBA that you can copy/paste into your VBA editor.

**make_vba_multiline.py**:

```
import fileinput

print 'Dim str As String'
print 'str = ""'
to_print = []
for line in fileinput.input():
  line = line.strip('\n')
  line_vba = 'str = str & "%s"' % line.replace('"','""')
  to_print.append(line_vba)

all_lines = " & vbCrLf\n".join(to_print)
print all_lines
```

For example, if I have the following when I list the contents of `helper`:

```
$ ls -la helper/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 ben  staff  102 Apr 19 14:03 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 ben  staff  238 Apr 19 14:03 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ben  staff  262 Apr 19 13:56 make_vba_multiline.py
```

When I pipe it into the script, I get:

```
$ ls -la helper/ | python helper/make_vba_multiline.py
Dim str As String
str = ""
str = str & "total 8" & vbCrLf
str = str & "drwxr-xr-x@ 3 ben  staff  102 Apr 19 14:03 ." & vbCrLf
str = str & "drwxr-xr-x@ 7 ben  staff  238 Apr 19 14:03 .." & vbCrLf
str = str & "-rw-r--r--@ 1 ben  staff  262 Apr 19 13:56 make_vba_multiline.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative if you want to comment a lot of code:

In the VBA editor, go to `View`, `Toolbars`, `Customise...` or right click on the tool bar and select `Customise...`

Under the `Commands` tab, select the `Edit` menu on the left.

Then approximately two thirds of the way down there's two icons, `Comment Block` and `Uncomment Block`.

Drag and drop these onto your toolbar and then you have easy access to highlight a block of code, and comment it out and uncomment with the click of a button!

Answer (score 0):

VBA syntax for that case should be

```vb
x = vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    "Hello" & vbCrLf & _
    "World " & vbCrLf
```

But there is a limit of line continuations, for Excel 2010 it is 24 for me. If you try to insert one more line with line continuation into the below string

```vb
x = vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    "Hello" & vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    "World " & vbCrLf
```

then you get the error message:

[image: Too many line continuations]

So the only way then to split the string to several multiline lines, as follows:

```vb
x = vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    "Hello" & vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf
x = x & vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    "World " & vbCrLf
```